# getting data from database and displaying on another page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

***** COMPLETE MODIFICATION OF THE PREVIOUS QUESTION ******

I have been developing an appointment system over the past few weeks using php, mysql and javascript. I've come across a problem when trying to insert data into a table. I am using javascript on a php page to send a GET request to a php file which generates a table from database records. I have

Comment: Sidenote: you realize that your values will fail.

Comment: visit http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and apply that to your query. You'll see what I mean.

Comment: edited code above. I select all records from a table and only populate the relevant text boxes with the relevant data from the result set

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand some of questions but as far as I know you want to call a data from the page?

You want to call the data from the specific users? If yes, you must use `$_GET` to get ID then you can call the data you want.

Please elaborate more regarding your question.

Comment: I have two tables - patients and requested_appointments. When the website loads it displays a table full of current patients and their details such as name, address, doctor etc.

Comment: When I click a button to request an appointment with that individual patient, I want the request an appointment form to load with their first name, second name and doctor in the individual text fields so they do not have to input the details of their name and doctor as it is already loaded in from the patients table.

Comment: would i just use _GET and then display the variale in the textfield? @Edmhar

Comment: How can your system know their Name? Your system have log in system?

Comment: I have re-worked this question. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.