# Retrieve data from a database and display in one cell of a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

[image]

I am building an doctors appointment system using php, javascript and html. I have a problem displaying multiple database results in one cell of a table. For example, I have a one week table displaying the date for 5 days of a week and also 9-5 time slots. I have a database that holds data for 9-5 for 5 days in a week. (Hope that makes sense ). I have a column name that is called appointment_availability and all slots are set to Y. (So they are all available). My problem is that I want to display the doctor_id in each table cell for all the doctors that are available. I'm unsure how to do this and at the minute it is displaying each doctor_id on a new row of my html table... Each cell should display doctor_id 1,2 & 3 because each doctor is available for every hour, all week. I know this may not be clear but its hard to explain...

my code is:

```
<?php
echo "
    <table width='80%' align='center' >
<div id='head_nav'>
<tr>";
echo"<th>Time</th>
    <th>02-11-2015</th>
    <th>03-11-2015</th>
    <th>04-11-2015</th>
    <th>05-11-2015</th>
    <th>06-11-2015</th>
</tr>
</div>";

$sql = "SELECT doctor_id FROM appointment_slots WHERE appointment_avaliability = 'Y' AND appointment_date = '2015-11-02' AND appointment_time = '09:00:00';";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>09:00 - 10:00</th>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['doctor_id'] . $row['doctor_id'] .  $row['doctor_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>  </td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "</tr>";
}

 echo "<tr>
    <th>10:00 - 11:00</td>

        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </div>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>11:00 - 12:00</td>

        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

    </div>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>12:00 - 01:00</td>

        <td> </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

    </div>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>01:00 - 02:00</td>

        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </div>
</tr>

 <tr>
  <th>02:00 - 03:00</td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </div>
</tr>

     <tr>
  <th>03:00 - 04:00</td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </div>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>04:00 - 05:00</td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </div>
</tr>";

echo "</table>";

[![Image displaying my problem][1]][1]?>
```

The "Doctors Availability table" is where the problem lies. As you can see, it is printing the same doctor_id out 3 times where as it should be displaying 1,2,3 instead of 1,1,1.

I hope this makes sense, I have been trying to figure this out for days and had no luck. Can not find anything on google or stack overflow to help with this problem. Any ideas, solutions or if anyone can point me in the right direction it will be greatly appreciated!!

I have just realised that this approach is going to be fair too long and really bad programming practice. I am going to have to run lots of different queries to populate the table as the query is getting the date and time and each row of the table is a different day and time.

Is there any cleaner way to do this?

I just want to display a table showing the 3 doctors availability. for each day for a week.

Comment: You are displaying $row['docter_id'] 3x after one another. The iterator is not in the next row. Your select query returns 3 rows, one for each doctor

Comment: You need to do the loop on the individual td tag.

Comment: No. The problem lies in your failure to grasp the concept of normalisation (it can be a tricky one, at first). A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: What you are looking for is a crosstabulation or a pivot table. It's tricky if you are new to mysql, but then you can do this in a single query.

Comment: The complexity of a pivot table may not be worth it for your purposes because you are basically creating a one-off summary, so it's fine if you use several queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting data from database and displaying on another page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286809/getting-data-from-database-and-displaying-on-another-page)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't actually do this myself but i hope it shows the principle

change

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>09:00 - 10:00</th>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['doctor_id'] . $row['doctor_id'] .  $row['doctor_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>  </td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

to

```
echo "<tr><th>09:00 - 10:00</th><td>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo $row['doctor_id']; 
}
    echo "</td><td>  </td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
//      echo "</div>"; and remove the open div
    echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: there is a mismatched closing div in there

Comment: @RamRaider shouldn't be a div in there at all ;-)

Comment: @Dagon Thanks so much, this has worked. I understand the approach I have taken is messy, but I aren't really sure how to make this better. I have read into jQuery but arent sure if this is the right approach to take. Have you got any tips or information on how you would actually tackle this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>09:00 - 10:00</th>";
echo "<td>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row['doctor_id']
}
"</td>";
    echo "<td>  </td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You an use GROUP_CONCAT to take care of that for you. It's MySQL only, though:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(doctor_id SEPARATOR ',') as ids
FROM appointment_slots 
WHERE appointment_avaliability = 'Y' 
AND appointment_date = '2015-11-02' 
AND appointment_time = '09:00:00'
```

You may need to GROUP BY appointment_avaliability if you are in strict mode.

Answer (score -1):

So many things are going on in your script that make it very hard to understand. To simply print a mysql query into a table you can use the following code

```
<table>
<?php
$res = mysqli_query("select * from table");
for ($row == mysqli_fetch_row($res) 
{ 
?> 
<tr> 
  <td><?php echo $row[0]?><td>
  <td><?php echo $row[1]?><td>
  <td><?php echo $row[2]?><td>
</tr> 
<?php 
} 

?>
</table>
```

You can also replace the  with a loop if you want but it is up to you to fix the logic and make your queries more dynamic

You also need to rewrite your code with HTML as a base and php to fill in the gaps and not the other way around.